# Where does the extra character come from in my compression method?

Tags: .net, compression

I had a compress and a decompress method that used to add an extra empty character. I managed to fix it, but I'm not sure why the fixed worked and hope somebody could explain it to me.

The Fix (-1 from buffer.length in the following line):

```
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(bytes.Length - 1), 0, gzBuffer, 0, 4)
```

Original line:

```
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(bytes.Length), 0, gzBuffer, 0, 4)
```

The Functions:

```
Private Function Compress(ByVal bytes As Byte()) As Byte()
    Using ms As New MemoryStream()

        Using zip As New Ionic.Zlib.GZipStream(ms, Ionic.Zlib.CompressionMode.Compress, Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.BestCompression, True)
            zip.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
        End Using

        //ms.Position = 0
        Dim compressed As Byte() = ms.ToArray()

        Dim gzBuffer(compressed.Length + 4) As Byte
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(compressed, 0, gzBuffer, 4, compressed.Length)
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(bytes.Length -1), 0, gzBuffer, 0, 4)

        Return gzBuffer
    End Using
End Function

Private Function DeCompress(ByVal bytes As Byte()) As Byte()

    Using ms As New MemoryStream()
        Dim msgLength As Integer = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0)
        ms.Write(bytes, 4, bytes.Length - 4)

        Dim buffer(msgLength) As Byte

        ms.Position = 0
        Dim offset As Integer = 0
        Using zip As New Ionic.Zlib.GZipStream(ms, Ionic.Zlib.CompressionMode.Decompress)
            While offset < buffer.Length - 1
                offset += zip.Read(buffer, offset, buffer.Length - offset)
            End While
        End Using

        Return buffer
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd look at your `Stream.Read` code (which doesn't check the return value, or loop with a larger offset and smaller count, both of which are usually required)

Comment: @MarcGravell My original code had an offset of 4 in it, but I removed them as I thought it was unnecessary in .Net (I'll never need to determine the block size by looking at how many empty bytes there are at the beginning). Could you give an example as to what you mean, as I'm not entirely clear.

Comment: You are overwriting the first four bytes of the compressed data with the length integer. I'm surprised that you get anything out at all.

Comment: @MrShoubs `Read(buffer,offset,count)` **does not** guarantee to read `count` bytes; it guarantees to read either 0 (for EOF), or >0 and <=count bytes if data is available; you are supposed to check the return value, and read until you have read *the right amount* of data.

Comment: @Guffa I didn't know what that four bytes was for, so removed it from the code I posted here - I've edited the question to show the original code now. It still has exactly the same problem.

Comment: @MarcGravell Sounds like you are on to something here - can you post in an answer the code I should use. Are you talking about the .Read on both methods, I'm not entirely clear on how to implement what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's better, now the length doesn't overwrite part of the compressed data.

Now your problem is that you are not using the `Stream.Read` method correctly. The method returns the number of bytes read, which can be less than the number of bytes requested, so you have to get that return value and repeat the read until you have all the data:

```
Dim offset as Integer = 0
Using zip As New Ionic.Zlib.GZipStream(ms, Ionic.Zlib.CompressionMode.Decompress)
  Do While offset < buffer.Length
    offset += zip.Read(buffer, offset, buffer.Length - offset)
  Loop
End Using
```

Also, instead of writing a byte array to the memory stream, just create the memory stream from the array:

```
Using ms As New MemoryStream(bytes)
```

Instead of reading the memory stream into an array, just use the `ToArray` method:

```
Dim compressed As Byte() = ms.ToArray()
```

#### Edit:

The one-off problem in the code was due to how arrays are created in VB, using the highest index instead of the size, so the buffer should be created using:

```
Dim buffer(msgLength - 1) As Byte
```

Using the `Position` property when reading and writing the memory stream you can avoid creating extra buffers:

```
Private Function Compress(ByVal bytes As Byte()) As Byte()
  Using ms As New MemoryStream()
    ms.Position = 4
    Using zip As New GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress, True)
      zip.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
    End Using
    ms.Position = 0
    ms.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(bytes.Length), 0, 4)
    Return ms.ToArray()
  End Using
End Function

Private Function DeCompress(ByVal bytes As Byte()) As Byte()
  Dim msgLength As Integer = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0)
  Using ms As New MemoryStream(bytes)
    Dim buffer(msgLength - 1) As Byte
    ms.Position = 4
    Dim offset As Integer = 0
    Using zip As New GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Decompress)
      While offset < buffer.Length
        offset += zip.Read(buffer, offset, buffer.Length - offset)
      End While
    End Using
    Return buffer
  End Using
End Function
```

(Note: This code uses the standard .NET `GZipStream`.)

Comment: +1 for Good info, thank you, but the first block of code create an infinite loop as the offset never goes above 14 and buffer.length is 15 (-l from the length causes the original extra char problem). Also using `Using ms As New MemoryStream(bytes)` causes the exception "Bad GZip Header" when decompressing.

Comment: I've updated my code to include your changes, but I still have the original problem.

Comment: One other question Guffa - you said in a comment I'm overwriting the first 4 bytes of compressed data with the length integer... well I can't see the line of code where I do that? can you point it out to me please (in the original question code, not the current one).

Comment: @Mr Shoubs: You posted the original code that doesn't overwrite part of the data, which I referred to in the first sentence in the answer. I'm not sure why yo get the infinite loop. You have removed the original question, so no my answer doesn't make any sense at all any more. :(

Comment: you led me to the answer, so I'm accepting it. I tested my solution a couple of million times and it always worked correctly.

Comment: @MrShoubs: As your fix just removes a byte from the input, you should look for the reason outside the methods. It seems that the array that you send into the `Compress` method has an extra byte at the end.

Comment: I use `UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("This is a test")`, but this doesn't seem to add on an extra byte.

Comment: I always thought this was a pretty standard compression/decompression method. Is it not?

Comment: @MrShoubs: I found the actual error. When you create an array in VB, you specify the highest index, not the size, so you should create the buffer using: `Dim buffer(msgLength - 1) As Byte`.

Comment: Also, you can use `Position` when you read and write the memory stream, so that you don't have to create extra buffers. I added code above.